# Exception from remove method for the Asynchronous shared maps in Vert.x Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, maps, vert.x, shared

I wanted to know, when we use the function `remove(K k, Handler<AsyncResult<V>> resultHandler)` for the Asynchronous shared maps in vertx with java, do we remove the tuple (key, value) or only the value of the key K (and replace it with the null value)?

Because in the description of the `Interface AsyncMap<K,V>` in the explanation of the function `remove` we find :

> Remove "a value" from the map, asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

As in ANY (java) Map out there by `Remove "a value" from the map` we mean:

> remove a key-value pair (Map.Entry) from the map by a key

In Vertx's sharedMap it's exactly the same meaning.